# Access Token error on Nest

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token, nest-api

I'm building up a website to control Nest devices and I've been working perfectly getting "Access tokens", but since the a few days ago I've been experiencing a problem when trying to get the "Access token" and no matter what I do and how long I wait I'm always getting "An error occured while fetching client info".

I've tried making new accounts, new clients, using proxies, everything, and nothing seems to solve the problem.

Is anyone experiencing this too? Anyone knows what's going on in here?

This is what the website throws me.

[image: Can't get access token]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact call your are making?

Comment: @DavidW.Keith Just opening the Authorization URL `https://home.testc.nestlabs.com/login/oauth2?client_id=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX&state=STATE`

Comment: Just noticed a similar question to mine, the problem is that the Nest's developer displays this url, when it has changed, they haven't updated it. @DavidW.Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should've been pointing to: `home.nest.com/login/oauth2?client_id=XXXXX&state=STATE` instead of `home.testc.nestlabs.com/login/oauth2?client_id=XXXXX&state=STATE`. The Nest's developer site is outdated and displays an old URL.

Comment: Thanks! This has been fixed and you are now shown the updated URLs